# msxml domdocument stops working when I move to staging server

Tags: asp-classic, rss

I have some code that looks like this:

```
Set xmlHttp = Server.CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP")
xmlHttp.Open "Get", myRSSfile, false
xmlHttp.Send()
myXML = xmlHttp.ResponseText

Set xmlResponse = Server.CreateObject("MSXML2.DomDocument")
xmlResponse.async = false
xmlResponse.LoadXml(myXML)
Set xmlHttp = Nothing

Set objLst = xmlResponse.getElementsByTagName("item")
Set xmlResponse = Nothing

NoOfHeadlines = objLst.length - 1
Response.Write NoOfHeadlines
```

This worked find on my development server. When I moved it over to a staging server (which I have no control over, and no nothing about), NoOfHeadlines returns 0. It seems obvious to me that DomDocument is not working the way its supposed to.
Is this a version issue? How do I find out what version of DomDocument is on the staging server? 
Is there another possibility?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was

```
xmlHttp.Open "Get", myRSSfile, false
```

should be

```
xmlHttp.Open "GET", myRSSfile, false
```